# How to read Redis Cache from Azure APIM

Tags: azure, redis, azure-api-management

So we have a requirement where we need to access the Redis Cache directly from the APIM.The Redis Cache will be populated via some background jobs. Depending on the response from the Redis (the response will have a redirect uri)  we need to redirect.

cacheclient = {
"userid" : "abcd"
"url1" : "url1",
"url2" : "url2",
"usertype":"normal"
}

My problem is whatever I try it is not reading from the Redis.

We don't need cache-store-value since data will always be in redis

I created an inbound policy

<when condition="@(context.Variables.ContainsKey("cacheduser"))">

hit

@((string)context.Variables["cacheduser"])

Answer (score 0):

- you can use an add an external redis , to add an external redis in apim, you have to go under the enter cache tab and click add
  [image]
- you have to fill the subsequent form and click save
  [image]
- After that you will have add policy in inbound tab and outbound tab in the inbound processing tab
  [image]

under inbound tag

```
<cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false">
    <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
    <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
    <vary-by-header>Authorization</vary-by-header>
</cache-lookup>
```

under outbound tag

```
<cache-store duration="20" />
```

Refer this [MS DOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-cache-by-key) on custom policy on caching

Comment: Thanks but I have different use case. The one suggested by you is the normal external cache. I had confirmed from Microsoft that my requirement is still not supported in Azure Apim